# How do you delete a pointed to value? Is that possible?

Tags: python, pointers

Example:

```
a = 5
b = a
del b # but I want to delete the memory of a using b's pointer.
```

So if this worked proper "a" would then return nothing. Because it would not longer exist.

Is there a `b.object = None` solution or something? Or is this type of pointer behavior not possible?

Comment: `del b` impacts the *identifier*, not the *value*. Python doesn't use pointers; I'd recommend reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html.

Comment: Python is a garbage collected language. What is your actual intent in doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete an object and all references to it in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068576/delete-an-object-and-all-references-to-it-in-python)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Delete an object and all references to it in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068576/delete-an-object-and-all-references-to-it-in-python), [Pointers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106689/pointers-in-python). [How to delete every reference of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013304/how-to-delete-every-reference-of-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`del b` impacts the *identifier*, not the *value*. Python doesn't use pointers; I'd recommend reading [nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html).

---

This was originally a comment by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe).