# I want to know exactly about Python del reserved words

Tags: python, data-structures, del

I want to know exactly about Python del reserved words.
In the process of studying linked list, I got curious about del reserved words.
First, common frame code.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, nxt=None):
        self.data = data
        self.nxt = nxt
        
class NodeMgmt:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.head = Node(data)
        
    def add(self, data):
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node.nxt is not None:
            current_node = current_node.nxt
        current_node.nxt = Node(data)
        
    def desc(self):
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node:
            print(current_node.data)
            current_node = current_node.nxt
```

I don't understand the result value of this code

```py
    def delete(self,data):
        current_node = self.head          
        while current_node.data != data:
            current_node = current_node.nxt
        del current_node
```

```
lnk = NodeMgmt(1)
lnk.add(2)
lnk.desc() >>> 1 2
lnk.delete(2)
lnk.desc() >>> 1 2
```

I know the following code is correct.

```py
   def delete(self,data):
        current_node = self.head
        current_node_parent = self.head
        while current_node:
            if current_node.data != data: 
                current_node_parent = current_node
                current_node = current_node.nxt
            else:
                break
                
        current_node_parent.nxt = current_node.nxt
```

I would like to point out clearly for the flexible use of del

```py
li = [1,2,3]
li1 = li
li1.append(1)
print(li)
del li1[2:] 
print(li) # >>> [1,2]
del li1
print(li) # >>> [1,2] Why isn't this deleted?
```

Comment: Because you didn't `del li`?

Comment: There is no such thing as "del reserved words" in Python.

Comment: This would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73785112/i-want-to-know-exactly-about-python-del-reserved-words, if the first comment were an accepted answer.

Comment: Further to @mkrieger1, why should you expect `li` to be deleted?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think you got that link wrong; right now it points back to this question!

Comment: In the last example, we know that the list data type is a mutable data type.
So li1 and li are looking at the same address. So even if you change li1, li will change.
So I think li should be deleted if I do del li1, but I wonder why it will not be deleted.

Comment: You delete the name `li1`, not the data. The data might be freed automaically if you remove the last reference to it, but in this case it's still bound to `li`. To cite the documentation of [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=del#grammar-token-python-grammar-del_stmt): "Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace, [...]"

Comment: @TurePålsson Oops, thanks for noticing! I meant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54894279/how-do-you-delete-a-pointed-to-value-is-that-possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we first describe the useage of the `del` statement to answer the title:

1. When directly acting on a variable name (`del some_object`), it will delete the binding between the variable name and the object:

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> globals()
{'__name__': '__main__',
 '__doc__': None,
 '__package__': None,
 '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000025FF6957C40>,
 '__spec__': None,
 '__annotations__': {},
 '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>,
 'foo': 1}
>>> del foo
>>> globals()
{'__name__': '__main__',
 '__doc__': None,
 '__package__': None,
 '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000025FF6957C40>,
 '__spec__': None,
 '__annotations__': {},
 '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>}
```

There is no direct relationship with garbage collection here. It just deletes the key value pair with `foo` as the key from the namespace, and decreases the reference count of the object bound before `foo` by one. When the reference count of an object decreases to 0, it will be collected as garbage.

2. When used for subscript (`del some_object[subscript]`), it delegates the deletion behavior to the object's `__delitem__` method:

```
>>> class Foo:
...    def __delitem__(self, item):
...        print('deleting', item)
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> del foo[0]
deleting 0
>>> del foo[:]
deleting slice(None, None, None)
```

3. When used for attribute (`del some_object.attribute`), it delegates the deletion behavior to the object's `__delattr__` method:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __delattr__(self, item):
...         print('deleting', item)
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> del foo.attr
deleting attr
>>> del foo.foo
deleting foo
```

---

Next is the answer to the question in the description:

> I don't understand the result value of this code
>
> ```
>     def delete(self,data):
>         current_node = self.head          
>         while current_node.data != data:
>             current_node = current_node.nxt
>         del current_node
> ```
>
> ```
> lnk = NodeMgmt(1)
> lnk.add(2)
> lnk.desc() >>> 1 2
> lnk.delete(2)
> lnk.desc() >>> 1 2
> ```

What you do here is: iterate the linked list, find the target node and bind the `current_node` to it, finally unbind the `current_node` to it. The whole process will not affect the linked list and target node, only the namespace. (and even if the `del` statement can successfully reclaim the node, the linked list will be disconnected from the middle.)

> I would like to point out clearly for the flexible use of del
>
> ```
> li = [1,2,3]
> li1 = li
> li1.append(1)
> print(li)
> del li1[2:] 
> print(li) # >>> [1,2]
> del li1
> print(li) # >>> [1,2] Why isn't this deleted?
> ```

This involves the use of two different `del` statements:

- `del li1[2:]` delegates the deletion to the list itself. Python's implementation is to delete the elements in the list within the slice range.
- `del li1` only unbinds `li1` from the list, because `li` still binds the list, it will not be collected as garbage. Only when you also unbind the list from `li` will the list be collected. At the same time, because there is no longer a variable name bound to it, you cannot access the list that has been collected.