# How do I create a list of explicit references in Python?

Tags: python, del

In Python 3, passing a reference to an object in name space to `del` does not work when wrapped in a list.

```
a = 'foo'

for x in [a]:
    del(x)
print(a)

del(a)
print(a)
```

The first call to `del` silently does nothing, only the second one deletes `a`. Why does this happen, and how would I pass references in a list to `del` to delete the reference (in this case `a`)?

Comment: My best guess is that `del` deletes the reference in the list. Still, how would I need to construct the list so that it contains a reference to `a` so it get's deleted from name space?

Comment: The first code deletes the iterator, not the actual strings

Comment: Objects don't know what names point to them. So trying to deleting a name from an object reference is doomed. Thankfully, you never need to do this. If you need to associated a name with an object, you can use a dictionary.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013304/how-to-delete-every-reference-of-an-object-in-python) answer the question?