# why deleting a node of linked list using del in python does not automatically changes the previous node's next pointer to None

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list, del

I created a linked list using 3 node. Then I deleted the last node using del keyword
I also tried assigning last node None. When I printed the linked list, no change was there

Why is it not working. please guide me about the concept I am missing
Thank You

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data= data
        self.next = None
    def printLL(self):
        temp = self
        while(temp):
            print(temp.data, end=" ")
            temp = temp.next
        print("None")
        print()

# creating linked list
head = node(1)
node2 = node(2)
node3 = node(3)
head.next = node2
node2.next = node3
head.printLL()

#deleting the last node
del node3
# or
# node3 = None

head.printLL()
```

output

```
1 2 3 None

1 2 3 None
```

expected output

```
1 2 3 None

1 2 None
```

Comment: `del node3` only deleted the `node3` **reference** to the `node(3)` object, not this object itself.

Comment: why node3 = None don't work. same reason?

Comment: For the same reason; you just point the `node3` reference to another object (None in this case), but `node(3)` still exists, and `node2.next` still references it.

Comment: Related: [How to delete every reference of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013304/how-to-delete-every-reference-of-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement the delete function separately.

You need to set `next` of second last node to None

```
node2.next = None

del node3
```

Have a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deletion-in-linked-list/) for more detail.